# Combine two normal distributions with one the mean of the other

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

For an assignment, I need to find $E_{y|\theta} [- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2\theta} \ln[P(y|\theta)] ]$,  where $y \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, 1)$ and $\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \delta^2)$.

I can handle taking the partial derivatives, log, etc.  Where I am stumbling is in finding $f_{y|\theta}$.

I keep coming back to simply plugging in $\theta$ for $\mu$ in the regular normal dist. equation. But I can't believe that this is correct since otherwise, where would the effect of $\theta$'s distribution be represented?

Perhaps another way I might ask this is:  How is $P(y|\theta)$ different from $P(y)$?

Comment: Didn't you already specify that $f_{y|\theta}$ is that of a $N(\theta, 1)$?

Comment: The difference between these to probabilities is that, because of Bayes's theorem, $P(y|\theta) = P(y)P(\theta|y)/P(\theta) $.

Comment: @Glen_b, Nestor,  thanks for your input. I remain confused though:  How does $\theta$ impact the expected value?  How do I include $\theta$'s distribution in the calculation of $E_{y|\theta}$.  Or does it not matter?

Comment: By definition, $E_{y|\theta}$ depends on $\theta$: that's how $\theta$ affects the expected value!

Comment: Yep, get that $E_{y|\theta}$ depends on $\theta$ by definition. I am confused as to how I incorporate this dependency when I calculate the above expected value. How would such a computation be any different having or not having the information about $\theta$?

Comment: To help you think about this: What happens to the expectation of something with mean $0$ when you then add $\theta$ to all the values? What's the expectation of a $\rm{N}(\theta,1)$ when $\theta = 0$?

Comment: @Glen_b would you care to expand upon your comment here as an answer?

Comment: The plan at the time was to offer a leading question as a hint rather than do someone's homework. I'm unsure that I can make that attempt at a socratic response into a suitable answer (I barely felt it was worth a comment but I was having trouble understanding OPs lack of comprehension and so couldnt think of a better response). If you see a suitable answer in it, by all means...